# Looking for a log thats bound to sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo

I've issued the commands sudo su, and sudo sh. Can you please tell me if there are logs associated with sudo, and where I could find them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for `sudo` or `su`. log in `/var/log/auth.log`

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log | egrep -i "(sudo|su)"`

If you would like colorized logs install `ccze` then pipe the output to `ccze`

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log | ccze`

Answer (score 2):

The next command searches for `sudo` in the logfile as used by `sudo` and `su`.

```
grep sudo  /var/log/auth.log
```